# Keeping position of a collection and changing the position

Tags: c#, math

I have multiple entities in the database that have a position assigned to them, the position starts from 0. I have a function that allows you to change the position of one of the entities and then it should recalculate it's position and the positions around it so there are no duplicates.

For example changing the position of the first entity to position 2:

```
Old Position | New Position
0            | 2
1            | 0
2            | 1
3            | 3
```

This is my code so far.

```
public static IList<Image> ReorderImages(List<Image> entities, int id, int position)
{
    var ordered = entities.OrderBy(x => x.Position).ToList();
    var positionIndex = ordered.FindIndex(x => x.Position == position);
    var maxItem = ordered.Max(x => x.Position);
    if (positionIndex == -1)
    {
        positionIndex = maxItem;
    }
    if (maxItem < position)
    {
        position = maxItem;
    }
    var indexToChange = ordered.FindIndex(x => x.Id == id);
    for (int i = 0; i < ordered.Count; i++)
    {
        var index = i;
        if (i == indexToChange)
        {
            ordered[i].Position = position;
            continue;
        }
        if (i <= positionIndex)
        {
            ordered[i].Position = index - 1;
        }
        if (i > positionIndex)
        {
            ordered[i].Position = index;
        }
    }
    return ordered;
}
```

But this for example the following unit test I wrote is breaking

```
[Test]
public void PositioningHelper_Reorder_Middle()
{
     List<Image> dbList = new List<Image>
    {
        new Image { Id = 1, EntityId = 1, Position = 0 },
        new Image { Id = 2, EntityId = 1, Position = 1 },
        new Image { Id = 3, EntityId = 1, Position = 2 },
        new Image { Id = 4, EntityId = 1, Position = 3 },
        new Image { Id = 5, EntityId = 1, Position = 4 },
    };
    List<Image> expectedPositionList = new List<Image>
    {
        new Image { Id = 1, EntityId = 1, Position = 1 },
        new Image { Id = 2, EntityId = 1, Position = 2 },
        new Image { Id = 3, EntityId = 1, Position = 0 },
        new Image { Id = 4, EntityId = 1, Position = 3 },
        new Image { Id = 5, EntityId = 1, Position = 4 },
    };
    var response = PositioningHelper.ReorderImages(dbList, 3, 0);
    foreach (var r in response)
    {
        var expected = expectedPositionList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == r.Id);
        Assert.That(r.Position, Is.EqualTo(expected.Position));
    }
}
```

How can I fix this method to allow me to change a position of a single item and for it to re-calculate the order of the rest?

This also does not look like the best way to approach this

Update
Further explanation

I need a method that will take a collection of `Image` and I need to be able to pass in the `Id` of an `Image` and the new position of that `Image`. The method should set the new position to what I passed in, and then re-calculate all of the other positions in the collection seeding it from `0`.

So if I passed in the Id of 1 and Position 4 (when the current position is 0), It should set the position of Id 1 as position 4, and then ID 2,3,4,5 should be  position 0,1,2,3.

Comment: Is your "database" an actual database, or is it a local collection?  This will determine the type of optimizations that can be applied.

Comment: It's a local collection in this case, but it's a collection from the database.

Comment: Updated to include full method signature and a unit test example @BradleyUffner

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: @Joel How to write/correct the method to allow reordering of any of the items and for it to recalculate all of the positions

Comment: @Barns Sorry, I clearly didn't explain myself that well. I have updated the bottom of the Question with some clarification. Sequential ordering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of the code requirements is there is a `List` of `Image` objects. An `Image` object has properties `Id`, `EntityId`, `Position`. A method should be developed that takes and rearranges the `List` such that an "Id" and "position" are give, that define which element (according to id) should be moved to which new position (according to the position, given).

Here would be my suggestion of how to implement.

```
    private static void ReorderListCleanVersion(List<ImagePos> entities, int id, int position)
    {
        if (entities == null) return;
        if (!entities.Any(a => a.Id.Equals(id))) return;
        if (!entities.Any(a => a.Postion.Equals(position))) return;

        var currentValue = entities.ElementAt(position);
        if (currentValue.Postion.Equals(id)) return;

        var tempValue = entities.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id.Equals(id));
        var isRemoved = entities.Remove(tempValue);

        if (!isRemoved) return;

        entities.Insert(position, tempValue);

        int pos = 0;
        entities.ForEach(f => f.Postion = pos++);
    }
```

**Code Explained**
The above clean version is without any comments or logging (below is a console executable version with comments and logging).

1) A null object test is performed -- we don't want any NullObjectException.
2) Make certain that an element exists with an `Id` equal to the id parameter, otherwise we would get an error when an attempt was made to remove the element, later.
3) Make certain that an element exists with a `Position` equal to the position parameter, otherwise we would get an error while an attempt was made to verify whether we are trying to move the element that is already in the position we want to move. We can't rely on position == id since they might not be the same.
4) Now, find the element where `Image.Id == id` and...
5) ...then remove it.
6) If the element was successfully removed, then `Insert` that `Image` object in the defined position.
7) Use the `Foreach` method of the `List` object to iterate through the `List` and reassign the `Position` property value.

**Note:**
The following two lines of code are not absolutely necessary, but why continue when the object is already in the position it should be moved.

```
var currentValue = entities.ElementAt(position);
        if (currentValue.Postion.Equals(id)) return;
```

---

**Executable code:**

```
private static void StartReorderListTest()
{
    var entities = new List<ImagePos>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        var u = new ImagePos()
        {
            Id = i,
            Postion = i,
            EntityId = 1
        };
        entities.Add(u);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("START");
    entities.ForEach(f => Console.WriteLine($"id{f.Id} Pos{f.Postion}"));

    TestReorderListComments(entities, 4, 0);
    Console.WriteLine("New Order");
    entities.ForEach(f => Console.WriteLine($"id{f.Id} Pos{f.Postion}"));
    Console.WriteLine("End");
}


private static void TestReorderListComments(List<ImagePos> entities, int id, int position)
{
    if (entities == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Null Object");
        return;
    }
    if (!entities.Any(a => a.Id.Equals(id)) || !entities.Any(a => a.Postion.Equals(position)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Mistake");
        return;
    }

    //Not necessarily postion == id
    var currentValue = entities.ElementAt(position);
    if (currentValue.Postion.Equals(id))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No need to move");
        return;
    }

    var tempValue = entities.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id.Equals(id));
    var isRemoved = entities.Remove(tempValue);

    if (!isRemoved) //Just in case
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Could not Remove");
        return;
    }

    entities.Insert(position, tempValue);

    Console.WriteLine("Reinserte");
    entities.ForEach(f => Console.WriteLine($"id{f.Id} Pos{f.Postion}"));

    int pos = 0;
    entities.ForEach(f => f.Postion = pos++);
}

public class ImagePos
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Postion { get; set; }
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
}
```

---

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Very good answer and you have really put the effort in here! Thank you, I will test and let you know!

Comment: Jamie, did you get an opportunity to try the code? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the item from the list and re-add it. It will look much clearer.

Also, you don't need to re-calculate the entire list, just the items between the current position and the target.

```
public static IList<Image> ReorderImages(List<Image> entities, int id, int position)
    {
        var ordered = entities.OrderBy(x => x.Position).ToList();

        var currentPosition = ordered.FindIndex(x => x.Id == id);
        var item = ordered[currentPosition];

        ordered.RemoveAt(currentPosition);
        item.Position = position;
        ordered.Insert(position, item);

        if (currentPosition < position)
        {
            for (int i=currentPosition; i< position; i++)
            {
                ordered[i].Position--;
            }

        } else
        {
            for (int i = position + 1; i <= currentPosition; i++)
            {
                ordered[i].Position++;
            }
        }
        return ordered;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure I understand the re-ordering requirements.  But getting the unit test to pass is simple enough if you just re-number them in place but skip the appropriate number and image.  Something like this works:

```
class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    public static IList<Image> ReorderImages(List<Image> entities, int id, int position)
    {
        Image targetToChange = entities.Find(i => i.Id == id);
        targetToChange.Position = position;

        int pos = 0;

        foreach (var image in entities)
        {
            if (image.Id == id)
                continue;

            if (pos == position)
                ++pos;

            image.Position = pos++;
        }

        return entities;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Image> dbList = new List<Image>
        {
            new Image { Id = 1, EntityId = 1, Position = 0 },
            new Image { Id = 2, EntityId = 1, Position = 1 },
            new Image { Id = 3, EntityId = 1, Position = 2 },
            new Image { Id = 4, EntityId = 1, Position = 3 },
            new Image { Id = 5, EntityId = 1, Position = 4 },
        };
        List<Image> expectedPositionList = new List<Image>
        {
            new Image { Id = 1, EntityId = 1, Position = 1 },
            new Image { Id = 2, EntityId = 1, Position = 2 },
            new Image { Id = 3, EntityId = 1, Position = 0 },
            new Image { Id = 4, EntityId = 1, Position = 3 },
            new Image { Id = 5, EntityId = 1, Position = 4 },
        };

        var ordered = ReorderImages(dbList, 3, 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < expectedPositionList.Count; ++i)
        {
            var left = ordered[i];
            var right = expectedPositionList[i];

            if (left.Id != right.Id || left.EntityId != right.EntityId || left.Position != right.Position)
                throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}
```